# Large factorial using BigIntegers losing precision

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger, factorial

It'sa me, with another problem.

I need to calculate a factorial of a really huge number, lets assume it is 95.
So as we all know **95!** equals to:

> 10329978488239062144133688859495761720042551046933218543167809699858950620982142410696539365993509132394773015016946331626553858953528454377577119744

I have used a simple method calculating factorials using BigIntegers that I found somewhere around here few months ago:

```
public static BigInteger FactorialTest(BigInteger x)
{
    if (x == 0)
        return 1;

    BigInteger res = x;
    x--;
    while (x > 1)
    {
        res *= x;
        x--;
    }
    return res;
}
```

And only got a rounded up number:

> 10329978488239059262599702099394727095397746340117372869212250571234293987594703124871765375385424468563282236864226607350415360000000000000000000000

Next step was using the builtin BigInteger methods for addition, multiplication etc, hoping it will fix the problem - no still did not work.

Last thing I tried was using code of someone smarter, so reached for SolverFoundation, unfortunately

> Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Common.BigInteger.Factorial(95)

still returns the rounded up number.

Is there anything I am missing that could get me the proper result? I really hoped BigIntegers would not lose precision like that.

Comment: Where did you get the expected results?  You are multiplying by 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90 so you should have at least 9 zeroes on the end.

Comment: According to [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=95!) we don't all know that 95! is the result you think it is. Where did you get that wrong number from?

Comment: btw, only the first 15 digits match! That is a huge difference, not just a rounding issue.

Comment: @jdweng holy, how could I missed that, thanks! The wrong number came from octave, guess I missed something (used num2str(factorial(95))) to get the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://2000clicks.com/MathHelp/BasicFactorialTable.aspx and other sites the number you are getting from your calculation is correct.

Comment: You are right, thank you! I have complately missed a fact pointed out by @jdweng. I also used octave wrong to get a number that appeared wrong.